# Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

So I'm trying to manually update hash for one user. I tried updating view, as tables are not visible.

I tried starting in single user mode, changing "sp_configure 'Allow updates',1", and so on, with no luck.

Is there any way. I don't know passwords, just hashes, as updating from 2000 SP4 to 2008 R2 failed, and I need to have credentials on 2008 R2, just like on old 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sp_Configure` 'Allow Updates' setting has had no effect since SQL Server 2005, it will still "work" but it won't do anything.

I believe that if you really must make these changes, you can do so by connecting through the DAC (Dedicated Administrator Connection) while the instance is in single user mode, but be careful what you change :)

[How to: Use the Dedicated Administrator Connection with SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Already tried DAC, but couldn't login. Didn't know that it should be in single user mode.

Comment: Thank goodness for this. Without this any dba could go and disable all auditing triggers and no one would ever know. this is the only way that quite a few auditing systems are based on -  checking when e.g. triggers are changed without the chance of anybody altering it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running SQL Server 2000 or earlier you can run:

```
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

Comment: This answer only applies to SQL Server 2000 and below and should be removed.

Comment: @FindOut_Quran whilst the actual line will "complete successfully", it doesn't actually do anything - the same error will persist even after running this command, as it was depreciated from SQL Server 2005