# SQL Sever 2016 Alter Table Valued Function -- Alter Security Policy

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2016, security-policy

I have a table-valued function which is being referenced by a security policy.
I want to `ALTER` the function, but I cannot:

> Msg 3729, Level 16, State 3, Procedure accessPredicate, Line 1
>   Cannot ALTER 'rls.accessPredicate' because it is being referenced by object 'EventSecurityPolicy'

Hmm but where is the security policy found in the GUI? I've checked the schema, table, and the function. I would assume that it would be under policies

[image]

Ok well I can always do it with T-SQL

```
select * 
from sys.security_policies
```

Maybe I can just turn it off

```
Alter security policy rls.EventSecurityPolicy
with (state = OFF);
```

Nope same error:

> Msg 3729, Level 16, State 3, Procedure accessPredicate, Line 1
>   Cannot ALTER 'rls.accessPredicate' because it is being referenced by object 'EventSecurityPolicy'

OK let's delete it

```
delete from sys.objects
where schema_id = schema_id('rls') and object_id='1253579504'
```

> Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

[How do you get past this sort of error: "Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189469/how-do-you-get-past-this-sort-of-error-ad-hoc-updates-to-system-catalogs-are-n)

OK I'll alter the assembly..

```
select * from sys.assemblies
```

[image]

Ok I have no idea where to go from here....

There must be an easier way! I just want to alter a function!

Comment: try this `ALTER SECURITY POLICY yourpolicy
    DROP  filter/block PREDICATE ON table`

Comment: Perfect thank you... as a note I had to include the AFTER UPDATE for the Block predicate... otherwise it says the predicate doesn't exist.

Add as an answer & I'll mark correct

Comment: you can post that as an answer ,with what you had and what were you trying and what you did,it may help others in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution --**

Drop the Predicates:

```
ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.EventSecurityPolicy DROP filter PREDICATE ON 
dbo.Dim_event
ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.EventSecurityPolicy DROP BLOCK PREDICATE ON 
dbo.Dim_event AFTER UPDATE
```

Then modify the function:

[image]